# Creating a Word Document using XML and C#

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word

I've created an xml template for a report. A user is supposed to be able to add information to personalise this report to their own needs by a program im creating in C#

How can I edit the contents of an entity then from what a user puts into a textbox and then display this on word?

Comment: What do you mean an XML Template? Is this some sort of MS Word document? How did you create it? Which version of Word and what commands did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a ton of information on the net about creating Word documents using XML and C#.  There are lots of possibilities.

Microsoft publishes something they call the "[Open XML Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905496.aspx)" that  helps with this.

Try [this search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=office+sdk+XML+C%23&form=QBRE3).

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850833.aspx) provides a bunch of "how to" articles summarizing how to fiddle with Word documents using XML and C#.